# Does every non-trivial subgroup of $S_9$ containing an odd permutation necessarily contain a transposition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Does every non-trivial subgroup of $S_9$ containing an odd permutation necessarily contain a transposition?

Here $S_9$ denotes the group of all permutations (i.e. bijections with itself) of the set $\{1,2, \ldots, 9 \}$ under the binary operation of composition of functions.

By a transposition is meant a permutation that leaves all elements except two fixed, mapping either of these two onto the other.

A permutation can only be expressed either as a product of an even number of transpositions or as a product of an odd number of transpositions (but not both) and as such is defined to be even or odd, respectively.

Reference: Fraleigh p. 95  Question 23d. in A First Course in Abstract Algebra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $\sigma=(1\ 2)(3\ 4)(5\ 6)$ and $H=\langle\sigma\rangle$.

Comment: I think the question could sound better if one replaces S$_9$ by $S_4$ or $S_5$.

Comment: user yesterady, What would be the situation in either of those cases?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Consider the cyclic subgroup generated by the element $\sigma = (1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$...